# Why I cannot decode QR codes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, qr-code, rgba

I am developing angular application and trying to decode image with QR code on client side only and facing with next errors.

I have next flow:

1. User uploads image.
2. I decode qr code from image.

`<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*"(change)="qrCodeUploaded($event.target.files)"/>`

I have tried next libraries:

1. https://github.com/zxing-js/library

```
  qrCodeUploaded(files: FileList): void {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const codeReader = new BrowserQRCodeReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

    fileReader.onload = (e: any) => {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = e.target.result;
        setTimeout(() => codeReader.decodeFromImage(image,  e.target.result).then(res => console.log(res)), 100);
    };
  }
```

Works for some of qr codes, but issues on mobile. If you will take a photo of QR code with your phone, it will be not decoded. So for mobile you will need to implement video.

2. https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR

```
  qrCodeUploaded(files: FileList): void {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = (e: any) => {
      console.log(new Uint8ClampedArray(e.target.result));
      console.log(jsQR(new Uint8ClampedArray(e.target.result), 256, 256));
    };
  }
```

I get next error for any QR images I upload:

```
core.js:15714 ERROR Error: Malformed data passed to binarizer.
    at Object.binarize (jsQR.js:408)
    at jsQR (jsQR.js:368)
```

gist link: 
https://gist.github.com/er-ant/b5c75c822eb085e70035cf333bb0fb55

Please, tell me what I am doing wrong and propose some solution for QR codes decoding. Open for any thoughts :)

Comment: What does this have to do with encryption?

Comment: You read [the readme here](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR)? They are expecting an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) (i.e the pixel values), you are giving them an ArrayBuffer of your image file (i.e the binary content). That won't work. To get an ImageData from a Blob you can do `createImageBitmap(blob).then(bmp=> {
 const ctx = Object.assign(document.createElement('canvas'), bmp).getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(bmp, 0,0);
  return ctx.getImageData(0,0,bmp.width,bmp.height);
})`

Comment: @Kaiido helped converting image to ImageData format with libs for parsing jpeg and png. Thanks. will try your example and apply an answer

Comment: @Kaiido applied your solution in answer with some updates. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [second library](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR) I missed that it expects `ImageData` and I pass Binary Data.

Thus, we have 3 solutions how to convert Binary Data to `ImageData`:

1. Use `createImageBitmap` [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) solution with some updates, as proposed in comments doesn't work.

```
qrCodeUploadedHandler(files: FileList): void {
  const file: File = files[0];

  createImageBitmap(files[0])
    .then(bmp  => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

      const width: number = bmp.width;
      const height: number = bmp.height;
      canvas.width = bmp.width;
      canvas.height = bmp.height;

      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
      const qrCodeImageFormat = ctx.getImageData(0,0,bmp.width,bmp.height);
      const qrDecoded = jsQR(qrCodeImageFormat.data, qrCodeImageFormat.width, qrCodeImageFormat.height);
    });
}
```

2. Get `ImageData` from canvas.

```
qrCodeUploadedHandler(files: FileList): void {
  const file: File = files[0];
  const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

  fileReader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
    const img: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
      const width: number = img.width;
      const height: number = img.height;

      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;

      const canvasRenderingContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext('2d');
      console.log(canvasRenderingContext);

      canvasRenderingContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

      const qrCodeImageFormat: ImageData = canvasRenderingContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

      const qrDecoded = jsQR(qrCodeImageFormat.data, qrCodeImageFormat.width, qrCodeImageFormat.height);
      canvas.remove();
    };
    img.onerror = () => console.error('Upload file of image format please.');
    img.src = (<any>event.target).result;
}
```

3. You can parse images with `png.js` and `jpeg-js` libraries for `ImageData`.

Answer (score 1):

step:

1. Create a new image object from image file
2. Create a canvas
3. Draw the image to the canvas
4. Get ImageData through the context of canvas
5. Scan QR code with jsQR.

install:

```bash
npm install jsqr --save
```

code:

```js
// utils/qrcode.js
import jsQR from "jsqr"

export const scanQrCode = (file, callback) => {
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = file.content
  image.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
    console.log(
      "image on load, image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight",
      image.naturalWidth,
      image.naturalHeight
    )

    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas") // Creates a canvas object
    canvas.width = image.naturalWidth // Assigns image's width to canvas
    canvas.height = image.naturalHeight // Assigns image's height to canvas

    const context = canvas.getContext("2d") // Creates a contect object
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight) // Draws the image on canvas

    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight) // Assigns image base64 string in jpeg format to a variable
    const code = jsQR(imageData.data, image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight)

    if (code) {
      console.log("Found QR code", code)

      callback(code)
    }
  })
}
```

use:

```js
scanQrCode(file, (code) => {
    console.log(code.data);
});
```